# How many forms of Lord Narasimha are present?

Tags: vaishnavism, yoga, lakshmi, narasimha, upasana

It is mentioned that there are multiple forms of Lord Narasimha which are worshipped by specific groups of individuals, for instance:

Ugra Narasimha:Never to be worshipped in a household directly.
Yoga Narasimha:Worshipped for excellence in Yoga(Hatha Yoga if I'm not wrong)
Veera Narasimha
Lakshmi Narasimha

etc.Can someone provide a list of all forms of the Lord ,and the specific purposes/precautions in worshipping Him?Thank you.